# Is there a way to use VS 2010 with clang 9.0.0 version on Windows?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, clang

I have a project that can be compiled with clang 9.0.0 version and VS 2017, Windows.

clang is installed by pre-built binaries(Windows 32bit).

The problem is that the user environment for this project should use VS 2010.

If I compile in an environment with only VS 2010 for the same project, I get the following error:

```
clang: error: linker command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation).
```

I tried using the -v option and could not find a solution direction.

Issues related to VS 2010 and clang were only a few years ago.

At the clang document(https://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html), I found the sentence "Visual Studio 2017 or later."

Since previous versions of clang supported VS 2010, I wonder if the latest version of clang blocked VS 2010 or whether there is an option.(I could not find any VS related options in many of the clang -help options.)

If I can never use VS 2010 with the latest version of clang, I will try to use an older version of clang.(This is a way to avoid, but it's not impossible)

Comment: I'd upgrade from VS2010 (which is really old by now) to VS2017 (or even 2019).

Comment: I also think it's a good way to do it, but it's a situation where developers and users are different and users don't want to get away from the familiar environment.(This is why I would rather use an older version of clang)